# Spectrum of the Witten Laplacian on compact Riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, differential-operators, laplacian, index-theory

Below I have given what I am calling as the ${\rm Witten{-}Laplacian}_{s,p}$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ for any constant $s >0$ and $p \in C^2(M,g)$

- How generally is it true that this ${\rm Witten{-}Laplacian}_{s,p}$ is positive semi-definite?
- And when the above is true are there examples of compact manifolds and (preferably ``usual") functions on them $p$ s.t we know the exact spectrum of the corresponding ${\rm Witten{-}Laplacian}_{s,p}$? (or at least a lower bounds on its smallest non-zero eigenvalue)

  By "usual" functions I mean we do not assume that $f$ is Morse or that $f$ satisfies the confining or the Villani condition or such. And I happy to know if the above is known even for just spheres or AdS.

---

For ``nice" real valued functions $f$ on $(M,g)$ we have for the square of the gradient of $f$,

$\Vert {\nabla_g f} \Vert ^2 = g(\nabla_g f,\nabla_g f) =  \sum_{j=1}^n  \sum_{i=1}^n g^{ij} \partial_i f  \partial_j  f$

and the Laplacian of $f$ being,

$\nabla_g^2 f := \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g)}} \sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} \left (  \sqrt{\det(g)} g^{ij} \frac{f}{\partial x_j}\right )$

where we define the metric as $g = [g_{ij}] = g \left ( \partial_{x_i}, \partial_{x_j}  \right )$ and $g^{-1} = [g^{ij}]$.

Then the ``${\rm Witten{-}Laplacian}_{s,p}$" will be the operator mapping,

$$ C^2(M,g) \ni h \mapsto \left ( -s^2 \nabla_g^2 + \Vert{\nabla_g p}\Vert ^2 -s \nabla_g^2 p \right ) h \in C^2(M,g)$$

Comment: Since your operator is of the form "Laplacian + perturbation" it will be positive-definite (possibly modulo finite numbers of zero modes and negative modes) exactly as often as the Laplacian itself is. You probably want to look at works by Gilkey. I don't remember an exact reference off the top of my head though. There is a list of them in the physics-oriented review arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138.

Comment: Well, we do not want any negative eigenvalues at all. One thing that I guess is true is  that it is PSD over the span of the solutions $\{ \psi_s \}$ of the Fokker-Plank equation given as, $\frac{\partial \psi_s}{\partial t} = - \frac{1}{2s} \cdot {\rm Witten-Laplacian}_{s,p} ( \psi_s )$. So I believe it should be PSD on any function space in which the solutions of the Fokker-Plank are dense. But I dont know what is that function space.

Comment: The Fokker-Planck equation (?) you mention is (also) the heat equation for this "Witten-Laplacian" operator (possibly modulo an overall factor involving $s$) which therefore has the same domain as the general class of operators in the review I referenced above.

Comment: I cant see anything in that review which looks like the Witten-Laplacian! Am I missing something?

Comment: (2.1) apparently.

Comment: Okay! So you are setting $a$ there to $0$ and $b = \Vert{\nabla_g p}\Vert ^2 -s \nabla_g^2 p$ here. Wonder if these people can compute the eigenvalues for this!

Comment: Though, even if one does this identification, how does one get to the smallest positive eigenvalue from the heat-kernel expansion?